# Write lines to a file from less

Tags: less, stdout

While in `vim` I can write a range of lines from the file I'm viewing to another file.  For example,

```
:1,10 w outfile.txt
```

will write lines 1 through 10 to outfile.txt.

Can I do the same while I'm viewing a file using `less`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
10Gmm1G|mcat > outfile.txt
```

(typed within `less`) seems to work as long as the input doesn't fit in one screen (in which case all the input ends up in `outfile.txt` for some reason).

- `10G` brings you to line `10`
- `mm` sets the `m` mark there
- `1G` (same as `g` in this case) brings you to line 1
- `|m` pipe from the current line to mark `m`
- `cat > outfile.txt`: that's piped to that command.

Comment: I had to paste the command at the prompt because typing `10G` brought me to the 10th line before I could type the rest, but it did indeed work.

Comment: @eebbesen, well that was the point. See my edit

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @StephaneChazelas (as well as for your initial answer) -- it is now clear.

Comment: genius to the rescue again :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `view` which is the same as `vi -r`

Comment: That will work, but for large files I prefer to use `less` -- it is my understanding that `vi` causes the whole file to load at once.