# How do I write all lines from less to a file?

Tags: less

I've piped a command to `less`, and now I want to save the command's output to a file. How do I do that?

In this case, I don't want to use `tee`, I want a solution directly from less, so that I don't have to rerun a long-running command if I forgot to use `tee`.

This question is similar to this one, the only difference is that I want to save all of the lines, not a subset: [Write lines to a file from less](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115549/9041)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

From `less`, type <kbd>s</kbd> then type the file name you want to save to, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
From the `man` page, under `COMMANDS`:

```
s filename
      Save the input to a file.  This only works if the input is a pipe, not an ordinary file.
```

`man` page also states that, depending on your particular installation, the `s` command might not be available. In that case, you could go to line 1 with:

```
g or < or ESC-<
      Go to line N in the file, default 1 (beginning of file).
```

and pipe the whole content to `cat` with:

```
| <m> shell-command
      <m> represents any mark letter. Pipes a section of the input file to the
      given shell command. The section of the file to be piped is between the
      first line on the current screen and the position marked by the letter. 
      <m> may also be ^ or $ to indicate beginning or end of file respectively.
```

so either:

```
g|$cat > filename
```

or:

```
<|$cat > filename
```

i.e. type <kbd>g</kbd> or <kbd><</kbd> (*g* or *less-than*) <kbd>|</kbd> <kbd>$</kbd> (*pipe* then *dollar*) then `cat > filename` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
This should work whether input is a pipe or an ordinary file.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it without `tee` is as follows.
`less /path/to/input > /path/to/output`
The above will overwrite `/path/to/output` if it already exists.


To do the same, but append to `/path/to/output` is as follows.
`less /path/to/input >> /path/to/output`

To save the text in `less` after you have opened it, you can use the Save File feature.
When in `less`, press `s`. Then, type the file name.
If you used a pipe, the file will automatically be written to Working Directory.
If you did not use a pipe, you will open a file with the text (for which you can save).
I believe the file will be opened in `vim`.

Comment: I want a solution from `less` once I've already opened `less`.

Comment: I see. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You don't use less, you use tee and then pipe tee to less.

`./program | tee program.out | less`

Comment: In the question, I specifically asked for a solution that worked without `tee` once `less` had already been opened.