# Is there a tool to dynamically redirect output to a new file on request

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, stdout

I'm currently redirecting the output of a monitoring tool to a file, however what I'd like to do, is to redirect this output to a new file on my request (using a keybinding), without stopping the said tool.

Something like

```
monitor_program | handle_stdout
```

Where `handle_stdout` allows me to define a new file where to put the log at certain point.

I know I could easily write it, but I'm wondering if there's any tool that already allows this.

Comment: You could probably run `logrotate` with a custom config file manually, depending on the behaviour of your monitor_program, but that's somewhat hackish.

Comment: It seems like your edit is actually an answer to the question. In that case, please post it as an answer (self-answers are encouraged!) and remove the answer from your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll suggest a named pipe.

1. Create a pipe `mkfifo p` (call it whatever you want, if not 'p')
2. Create a "reader" script that reads from the pipe and writes wherever you like
3. Tell the monitoring program to write its logs to the named pipe

Here's a sample reader script that reads from a named pipe 'p' and writes the data to an indexed 'mylog' file:

```
#!/bin/sh

INDEX=0

switchlog() {
  read INDEX < newindex
  echo now writing to "mylog.$INDEX"
}

trap switchlog USR1

while :
do
  cat p >> mylog."$INDEX"
done
```

Comment: You could also trap a signal (USR1 for example) in the reader script as the signal to switch logs.

Comment: This starts to be something I'd need... However the reader script should be able to change the output based on a my kebinding. And potentially ask me for a new file name to use (although this is optional, even having sequential log names would be fine)

Comment: I edited the sample script to show an example of log-switching with kill -USR1. echo a new number into the 'newindex' file for it to pick up.

Comment: just another idea -- if you keep a window open for the running "reader" script, you could trap 'INT' instead of USR1 and just hit Control-C in that window to notify it of a new log filename.

Comment: Why `read` and `printf` instead of just `cat <p >> mylog."$INDEX"`?

Comment: @Wildcard only because I didn't think of it! I had to test it to convince myself that it works. That's a great idea! Can I steal it, or would you like to post it separately?

Comment: Last time I looked things (before systemd), `logrotate` and `syslogd` worked together by having `syslogd` always write to the same file.  `logrotate` would rename the current file that `syslogd` has open, then send it a signal.  At this point, `syslogd` would close the current output fd and re-open its output by name.  So all the name-choosing logic is in `logrotate`, not the program that receives `SIGUSR1`, and you can manually do whatever you want.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, go for it.  But it is slightly better to use `<p` instead of `p` in this particular case, so you get the error from the shell instead of from `cat` if `p` is not readable.

Answer (score 7):

Building up on your SIGINT idea, here using SIGQUIT (<kbd>Ctrl+\</kbd>) to you can still use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to stop the whole thing:

```
(trap '' QUIT; monitor_command) | (
   trap : QUIT
   ulimit -c 0 # prevent core dump so SIGQUIT behaves like SIGINT
               # for cat
   n=0; while n=$((n+1)); file=output.$n.log; do
     printf 'Outputting to "%s"\n' "$file"
     cat > "$file"
   done)
```

That assumes `cat` is not a builtin in your shell (so it does get interrupted by you press <kbd>Ctrl+\</kbd>).

Note that like in your approach, there's a chance that the SIGQUIT be delivered at the wrong time (in the write system call) causing some data to be lost.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use `less` and save from there by typing <kbd>s</kbd> then the file name you want to save to, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. From [How do I write all lines from less to a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172624/how-do-i-write-all-lines-from-less-to-a-file).

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to user more log files, once you've set one you can't redefine a new one. Also you can't clear the log once done. So... Good starting point (thanks), but no enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your "request" its not really possible to answer. If it were based on file size or interval, then [rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/rotatelogs.html) (which should come bundled with Apache httpd) would work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say that explicitly, I'm assuming a keybinding that would allow to change the log name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Jeff Schaller's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281036/168860), I ended up with something like this, which basically does what I need, let's call it `reader.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

INDEX=0
LOGNAME="$INDEX.log"

switchlog() {
  local custom_name
  read -p "Add log name: " custom_name
  INDEX=$((INDEX+1))
  LOGNAME="$(printf "%03d" $INDEX).$custom_name.log"
  echo now writing to $LOGNAME
}

trap switchlog INT
switchlog

while :
do
  read foo < p
  printf "%s\n" "$foo" >> "$LOGNAME"
done
```

Then it's just about creating a named pipe with `mkfifo p`, and using two terminals where `monitor_program > p` and `reader.sh` are running. I can then stop the reader to set a new log by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and enter a new name. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, as usual then to stop and kill it.